# Building a jQuery Image Slider with animation

Tags: jquery, html, image, animation, jquery-animate

So I'm somewhat new to jQuery, but I have a couple months experience. My question goes like this.

I built an image slider that loops through a `div` and animates the photos "sliding in right to left" when I click the NEXT button. My problem, however, is changing it to "slide left to right" when I click the previous button.

In my code I've tried moving my *animate margin-left.fadeOut* statement into the *if btn has class next* conditional, and replacing that with `.queue(function)`, `.css(function)`, `.animate(function)` and a few others, but nothing is seeming to work and I can't leave it on the top line because it effects the previous conditional which I want to work in the opposite that my next button is going.

I have been very much stuck on this for weeks and I keep coming back to this point that works halfway. Can anybody steer me in the right direction. I'm stumped.

Here is what I have so far.

```
<body>
    <section class="photos">
        <div class="slider">
            <div class="photo">
                <img src="images/photoOne.png">
            </div>
            <div class="photo hidden">
                <img src="images/photoTwo.png">
            </div>
            <div class="photo hidden">
                <img src="images/photoThree.png">
            </div>
        </div> 


    <div class="buttons">
        <a href="#" class="btn prev">Previous</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn next">Next</a>
    </div>
</section>
</body>

<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script>
var activePhoto = 0;

$('.btn').click(function() {

var $btn = $(this);

$photoBox.eq(activePhoto).animate({ 
"margin-left": "-=744px"}, "fast").fadeOut(function () {

    if ($btn.hasClass('next')) {
        if (activePhoto == $photoBox.length - 1) {
            activePhoto = 0;
        } else {
            activePhoto++;
        }

        $photoBox.eq(activePhoto - 1).css({
            "margin-left": "+=744px"
        });

        $photoBox.eq(activePhoto).css({
            "margin-left": "+=744px"
        });

        $photoBox.eq(activePhoto).fadeIn().animate({
            "margin-left": "-=744px"
        }, "fast");

    } else if ($btn.hasClass('prev')) {

        if (activePhoto == 0) {
            activePhoto = $photoBox.length - 1;
        } else {
            activePhoto--;
        }
    }

});

});

</script>
```

As I said, it works just fine like this when I click next, but getting it to do the opposite when I click previous is giving me problems. If this makes sense, this is what I was trying to do with my jQuery.

```
<script>
var activePhoto = 0;

$('.btn').click(function() {

var $btn = $(this);

$photoBox.eq(activePhoto).queue(function () {
    if ($btn.hasClass('next')) {

        if (activePhoto == $photoBox.length - 1) {
            activePhoto = 0;
        } else {
            activePhoto++;
        }

        $photoBox.eq(activePhoto - 1).animate({
           "margin-left": "-=744px"}, "fast").fadeOut();

        $photoBox.eq(activePhoto - 1).css({"margin-left": "+=744px"});

        $photoBox.eq(activePhoto).css({"margin-left": "+=744px"});

        $photoBox.eq(activePhoto).fadeIn().animate({"margin-left": "-=744px"}, "fast");

    } else if ($btn.hasClass('prev')) {

        if (activePhoto == 0) {
            activePhoto = $photoBox.length - 1;
        } else {
            activePhoto--;
        }

        $photoBox.eq(activePhoto + 1).animate({"margin-left": "+=744px"}, "fast").fadeOut();

        $photoBox.eq(activePhoto + 1).css({"margin-left": "-=744px"});

        $photoBox.eq(activePhoto).css({"margin-left": "-=744px"});

        $photoBox.eq(activePhoto).fadeIn().animate({"margin-left": "+=744px"}, "fast");

    }
});

});

</script>
```

I hope that makes sense :)

Here are two jsfiddles I have for my example. Perhaps this will illustrate my problem for you.
The first one is how it currently works with the next button and the images sliding from right to left. The second is what I am attempting to do, a reverse of the animation for the previous button with the image sliding out to the right of the caption, the subsequent image fading in on the left of the caption and then sliding in above the caption. Neither the previous nor next buttons work properly in the second example.

http://jsfiddle.net/jay_dub/dtdZc/

http://jsfiddle.net/jay_dub/naKub/

Comment: If you post questions please make sure that your code is indented, and that you add some formatting, otherwise it is really hard to read. Is  this a direct copy and past of your js code? Because this code has an not matching `});` at the end which would be a syntax error and would prevent your code from running.

Comment: I missed a newline after `Here is what I have so far.` so some html code is not displayed. I tried to correct, but my edit was rejected ;). So please add the newline yourself so that all html code is shown again, sorry about my mistake while editing.

Comment: I forgot to add the btn click function and my variable for the button, and fixed the formatting so the HTML displays again.

Comment: Thanks for helping format my code on here. This was my first question, and thought that all lines needed to be indented four spaces. My mistake. This looks better. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Well, I basically spend an hour preparing this for you so I hope you appreciate it :)

What you want to do is do the exact same backwards for if you click previous:

```
$(".btn_next").click(function()
   {
             $(".slider").animate({
            "margin-left": "+=-100px"
            }, "fast"); 
   });

$(".btn_prev").click(function()
   {
             $(".slider").animate({
            "margin-left": "+=100px"
            }, "fast"); 
           current--;
   });
```

But how to implement this?

Well, I prepared a live example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/qPPL8/5/

**Try to understand exactly what I do there and why it works.**

If you do that, you can use the exact same method for your code.

**NOTE:** I enhanced the code a bit to incorporate the fact that it is possible to 'run out of photos'. You can see how I did that with the `if statements` in the JsFiddle.

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but it's not quite what I'm looking for. For a couple of reasons, the first is that the loop slides the image in the wrong way, and the second is that I have a caption to go along with the photo which runs the same way on the same click. I like what you did and made a fiddle of my question as well so you can see where I'm going with it. Essentially I'm trying to make my previous button slide the image off to the right of the caption, fade the new image in on the left of the caption and slide it in above the caption.

Comment: And here is the problem I'm running into when I try and reverse it. http://jsfiddle.net/jay_dub/naKub/

Answer (score 0):

OK :) I got it!

Since I had two classes on my button I used took your idea of splitting them up as such

```
$('.next').click(function() {
  var $btn = $(this); 
  var $photoBox = $('.slider').find('.photo');
$photoBox.eq(activePhoto).animate({"margin-left": "-=744px"}, "fast").fadeOut(function() {
```

with the first half of the conditional statement and

```
$('.prev').click(function() {
  var $btn = $(this); 
  var $photoBox = $('.slider').find('.photo');
$photoBox.eq(activePhoto).animate({"margin-left": "+=744px"}, "fast").fadeOut(function() {
```

with the second half of the conditional statement which almost worked, but the math was still off for the previous button and wasn't reseting the correct photo, so I needed to subtract one less than the total number of photos (ie. 3 photos so -2) and everything worked brilliantly! Awesome!

Comment: So then can you accept my answer as 'the answer'? It is normal that if you post a question and somebody leads you to the answer that you 'thank them' by selecting their answer as 'the answer' (by clicking the green button next to the answer)

Comment: Also, if you look closely to my code, you see that I did the same with the 3 and -2 but I softcoded it instead of hardcoded.

Comment: Also, if you want to thank somebody even more, you can 'upvote' their answer. By doing this you will give them points for supplying a good answer and if you additionally accept their answer as 'the answer' then you also award them points for solving the issue. E.g.: I upvoted your answer so thats why you have 6 rep now. I hope that will help you get started here on Stack :)